# how to change sim 908 gps location coordinates format?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I use Sim908 module for record GPS location and Arduino.

Sim908 send the lat and lon in ddmm.mmmm format, but the major service of GPS location online (for example google earth) use the dd.dddd format.

So, How can modify my code to convert multiple coordinate that sim 908 send to dd.dddd format ?

Sim 908 Gsm Library Code

```
#include "gps.h"
char GPSGSM::getBattInf(char *str_perc, char *str_vol)
{
     char ret_val=0;
     char *p_char;
     char *p_char1;

     gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CBC");
     gsm.WaitResp(5000, 100, "OK");
     if(gsm.IsStringReceived("+CBC"))
          ret_val=1;

     //BCL
     p_char = strchr((char *)(gsm.comm_buf),',');
     p_char1 = p_char+1;  //we are on the first char of BCS
     p_char = strchr((char *)(p_char1), ',');
     if (p_char != NULL) {
          *p_char = 0;
     }
     strcpy(str_perc, (char *)(p_char1));

     //Voltage
     p_char++;
     p_char1 = strchr((char *)(p_char), '\r');
     if (p_char1 != NULL) {
          *p_char1 = 0;
     }
     strcpy(str_vol, (char *)(p_char));
     return ret_val;
}

char GPSGSM::getBattTVol(char *str_vol)
{
     char *p_char;
     char *p_char1;
     char ret_val=0;

     gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CBTE?");
     gsm.WaitResp(5000, 100, "OK");
     if(gsm.IsStringReceived("+CBTE"))
          ret_val=1;

     //BCL
     p_char = strchr((char *)(gsm.comm_buf),':');
     p_char1 = p_char+2;  //we are on the first char of BCS
     p_char = strchr((char *)(p_char1), '\r');
     if (p_char != NULL) {
          *p_char = 0;
     }
     strcpy(str_vol, (char *)(p_char1));
     return ret_val;
}

char GPSGSM::attachGPS()
{
     if(AT_RESP_ERR_DIF_RESP == gsm.SendATCmdWaitResp("AT+CGPSPWR=1", 500, 100, "OK", 5))
          return 0;
     if(AT_RESP_ERR_DIF_RESP == gsm.SendATCmdWaitResp("AT+CGPSRST=1", 500, 100, "OK", 5))
          return 0;
     return 1;
}

char GPSGSM::deattachGPS()
{
     if(AT_RESP_ERR_DIF_RESP == gsm.SendATCmdWaitResp("AT+CGPSPWR=0", 500, 100, "OK", 5))
          return 0;
     return 1;
}

char GPSGSM::getStat()
{
     char ret_val=-1;
     gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CGPSSTATUS?");
     gsm.WaitResp(5000, 100, "OK");
     if(gsm.IsStringReceived("Unknown")||gsm.IsStringReceived("unknown"))
          ret_val=0;
     else if(gsm.IsStringReceived("Not"))
          ret_val=1;
     else if(gsm.IsStringReceived("2D")||gsm.IsStringReceived("2d"))
          ret_val=2;
     else if(gsm.IsStringReceived("3D")||gsm.IsStringReceived("3d"))
          ret_val=3;
     return ret_val;
}

char GPSGSM::getPar(char *str_long, char *str_lat, char *str_alt, char *str_time, char *str_speed )
{
     char ret_val=0;
     char *p_char;
     char *p_char1;
     gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CGPSINF=0");
     gsm.WaitResp(5000, 100, "OK");
     if(gsm.IsStringReceived("OK"))
          ret_val=1;

     //longitude
     p_char = strchr((char *)(gsm.comm_buf),',');
     p_char1 = p_char+1;  //we are on the first char of longitude
     p_char = strchr((char *)(p_char1), ',');
     if (p_char != NULL) {
          *p_char = 0;
     }
     strcpy(str_long, (char *)(p_char1));

     // latitude
     p_char++;
     p_char1 = strchr((char *)(p_char), ',');
     if (p_char1 != NULL) {
          *p_char1 = 0;
     }
     strcpy(str_lat, (char *)(p_char));

     // altitude
     p_char1++;
     p_char = strchr((char *)(p_char1), ',');
     if (p_char != NULL) {
          *p_char = 0;
     }
     strcpy(str_alt, (char *)(p_char1));

     // UTC time
     p_char++;
     p_char1 = strchr((char *)(p_char), ',');
     if (p_char1 != NULL) {
          *p_char1 = 0;
     }
     strcpy(str_time, (char *)(p_char));

     // TTFF
     p_char1++;
     p_char = strchr((char *)(p_char1), ',');
     if (p_char != NULL) {
          *p_char = 0;
     }

     // num
     p_char++;
     p_char1 = strchr((char *)(p_char), ',');
     if (p_char1 != NULL) {
          *p_char1 = 0;
     }

     // speed
     p_char1++;
     p_char = strchr((char *)(p_char1), ',');
     if (p_char != NULL) {
          *p_char = 0;
     }
     strcpy(str_speed, (char *)(p_char1));

     return ret_val;
}

void parseTime(char *field, int *time)
{
     ////////////////Time////////////
     char tmp[4];
     tmp[2]=0; // Init tmp and null terminate
     tmp[0] = field[8];
     tmp[1] = field[9];
     time[0] = atoi(tmp); // Hours
     tmp[0] = field[10];
     tmp[1] = field[11];
     time[1] = atoi(tmp); // Minutes
     tmp[0] = field[12];
     tmp[1] = field[13];
     time[2] = atoi(tmp); // Seconds
     /////////////Date///////////////
     tmp[0] = field[0];
     tmp[1] = field[1];
     tmp[2] = field[2];
     tmp[3] = field[3];
     tmp[4]=0; // Init tmp and null terminate
     time[3] = atoi(tmp); // year
     tmp[0] = field[4];
     tmp[1] = field[5];
     tmp[2]=0; // Init tmp and null terminate
     time[4] = atoi(tmp); // month
     tmp[0] = field[6];
     tmp[1] = field[7];
     tmp[2]=0; // Init tmp and null terminate
     time[5] = atoi(tmp); // day
}

// Read the latitude in decimal format from a GGA string
double convertLat(char* latString)
{
     double latitude = atof(latString);                                    // convert to a double (precise)
     int deg = (int) latitude / 100;                               // extract the number of degrees
     double min = latitude - (100 * deg);                  // work out the number of minutes
     latitude = deg + (double) min/60.0;                   // convert to decimal format
     return latitude;
}

// Read the longitude in decimal format from a GGA string
double convertLong(char* longString)
{
     double longitude = atof(longString);                                  // convert to a double
     int deg = (int) longitude / 100;                              // extract the number of degrees
     double min = longitude - (100 * deg);                 // work out the number of minutes
     longitude = deg + (double) min/60.00;                 // convert to decimal format
     return longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python code may be useful for someone:

```
lat_conv = int(float(lat) / 100) + math.fmod(float(lat),100) / 60
lon_conv = int(float(lon) / 100) + math.fmod(float(lon),100) / 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution . every think is okay now .

My Final Code.

```
#include "SIM900.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ADXL345.h>

/*
Flame sensor      Arduino
VCC                 5V
GND                 GND
D0                  D2 (Digital pin 2)

tx   2
rx   3
*/
#include "gps.h"
#include "sms.h"

ADXL345 adxl; //variable adxl is an instance of the ADXL345 library
char aux_str[30];
char aux;

char latitude[15];
char longitude[15];
int x,y,z;  
int rawX, rawY, rawZ;
float X, Y, Z;
float rollrad, pitchrad;
float rolldeg, pitchdeg;

SMSGSM sms;
int D2 = 5; // digital pin 2
int numdata;
boolean started=false;
char smsbuffer[160];
char n[20]="0599122910";
GPSGSM gps;
char lon[15];
char lat[15];
char alt[15];
char time[20];
char vel[15];
char msg1[5];
char msg2[5];
char text[20];
char stat;
char inSerial[20];
int i=0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
   adxl.powerOn();

  pinMode(D2,INPUT);
        //Serial connection.
     Serial.begin(9600);
     Serial.println("GSM Shield testing.");
     //Start configuration of shield with baudrate.
     //For http uses is raccomanded to use 4800 or slower.
     if (gsm.begin(2400)) {
          Serial.println("\nstatus=READY");
          started=true;
            gsm.forceON();
     } else Serial.println("\nstatus=IDLE");


}

void loop() {
  int sensorReading = digitalRead(D2); // read the sensor on digital D2
  Serial.print(sensorReading);
    adxl.readAccel(&x, &y, &z); //read the accelerometer values and store them in variables  x,y,z
  // Output (x,y,z) on horizontal plane should be approximately (0,0,255) 
  // the following 3 lines is for an offset
  rawX=x-7;
  rawY=y-6;
  rawZ=z+10;

  X = rawX/256.00; // used for angle calculations
  Y = rawY/256.00; // used for angle calculations
  Z = rawZ/256.00; // used for angle calculations

  rollrad = atan(Y/sqrt(X*X+Z*Z));  // calculated angle in radians
  pitchrad = atan(X/sqrt(Y*Y+Z*Z)); // calculated angle in radians

  rolldeg = 180*(atan(Y/sqrt(X*X+Z*Z)))/PI; // calculated angle in degrees
  pitchdeg = 180*(atan(X/sqrt(Y*Y+Z*Z)))/PI; // calculated angle in degrees

  if (sensorReading==1  ) {       // No Flames Detected
    Serial.println(" - No Flames Near Sensor");
      Serial.print("\t Angle according to x axis (Roll(deg)) = "); Serial.print(rolldeg);      // calculated angle in degrees
  Serial.print("\t Angle according to y axis (Pitch(deg)) = "); Serial.println(pitchdeg);  // calculated angle in degrees
  }

  else {                       // Flames detected

    Serial.println(" - Flame Detected!");
        if(started) {
             //GPS attach
          if (gps.attachGPS())
               Serial.println("status=GPSREADY");
          else Serial.println("status=ERROR");

          delay(20000); //Time for fixing
          stat=gps.getStat();
          if(stat==1)
               Serial.println("NOT FIXED");
          else if(stat==0)
               Serial.println("GPS OFF");
          else if(stat==2)
               Serial.println("2D FIXED");
          else if(stat==3)
               Serial.println("3D FIXED");
          delay(5000);
          //Get data from GPS
          gps.getPar(lon,lat,alt,time,vel);
convert2Degrees(lat);
 convert2Degrees(lon);

  Serial.print(lat); Serial.print(",");Serial.print(lon);
          smsbuffer[0]='\0';

   strcat(smsbuffer," It was found in the fire site: ");
   strcat(smsbuffer,text);

  strcat(smsbuffer," latitude: ");
   strcat(smsbuffer,lat);
   strcat(smsbuffer,"longitude:  ");
   strcat(smsbuffer,lon);



     strcat(smsbuffer,"time:");
    strcat(smsbuffer,time);


  sms.SendSMS("0599122910", smsbuffer); 
        }
          if ( rolldeg >80&&pitchdeg >6 ){ 


            gps.getPar(lon,lat,alt,time,vel);
convert2Degrees(lat);
 convert2Degrees(lon);

  Serial.print(lat); Serial.print(",");Serial.print(lon);
          smsbuffer[0]='\0';

   strcat(smsbuffer," It was found in the fire site: ");
   strcat(smsbuffer,text);

  strcat(smsbuffer," latitude: ");
   strcat(smsbuffer,lat);
   strcat(smsbuffer,"longitude:  ");
   strcat(smsbuffer,lon);



     strcat(smsbuffer,"time:");
    strcat(smsbuffer,time);


  sms.SendSMS("0599122910", smsbuffer); 
  }


           //and write them on NewSoftSerial.
     serialhwread();
     //Read for new byte on NewSoftSerial.
     serialswread();


  }
     if(started) {
          //Read if there are messages on SIM card and print them.
          if(gsm.readSMS(smsbuffer, 160, n, 20)) {
               Serial.println(n);
               Serial.println(smsbuffer);
          }
          delay(1000);
     }
  };

void serialhwread()
{
     i=0;
     if (Serial.available() > 0) {
          while (Serial.available() > 0) {
               inSerial[i]=(Serial.read());
               delay(10);
               i++;
          }

          inSerial[i]='\0';
          if(!strcmp(inSerial,"/END")) {
               Serial.println("_");
               inSerial[0]=0x1a;
               inSerial[1]='\0';
               gsm.SimpleWriteln(inSerial);
          }
          //Send a saved AT command using serial port.
          if(!strcmp(inSerial,"TEST")) {
//      Serial.println("BATTERY TEST 1");
//      gps.getBattInf(msg1,msg2);
//      Serial.println(msg1);
//      Serial.println(msg2);
//      Serial.println("BATTERY TEST 2");
//      gps.getBattTVol(msg1);
//      Serial.println(msg1);
               stat=gps.getStat();
               if(stat==1)
                    Serial.println("NOT FIXED");
               else if(stat==0)
                    Serial.println("GPS OFF");
               else if(stat==2)
                    Serial.println("2D FIXED");
               else if(stat==3)
                    Serial.println("3D FIXED");
          }
          //Read last message saved.
          if(!strcmp(inSerial,"MSG")) {
               Serial.println(msg1);
          } else {
               Serial.println(inSerial);
               gsm.SimpleWriteln(inSerial);
          }
          inSerial[0]='\0';
     }
}

void serialswread()
{
     gsm.SimpleRead();
}

 int8_t convert2Degrees(char* input){

    float deg;
    float minutes;
    boolean neg = false;    

    //auxiliar variable
    char aux[10];

    if (input[0] == '-')
    {
        neg = true;
        strcpy(aux, strtok(input+1, "."));

    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(aux, strtok(input, "."));
    }

    // convert string to integer and add it to final float variable
    deg = atof(aux);

    strcpy(aux, strtok(NULL, '\0'));
    minutes=atof(aux);
    minutes/=1000000;
    if (deg < 100)
    {
        minutes += deg;
        deg = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        minutes += int(deg) % 100;
        deg = int(deg) / 100;    
    }

    // add minutes to degrees 
    deg=deg+minutes/60;


    if (neg == true)
    {
        deg*=-1.0;
    }

    neg = false;

    if( deg < 0 ){
        neg = true;
        deg*=-1;
    }

    float numeroFloat=deg; 
    int parteEntera[10];
    int cifra; 
    long numero=(long)numeroFloat;  
    int size=0;

    while(1){
        size=size+1;
        cifra=numero%10;
        numero=numero/10;
        parteEntera[size-1]=cifra; 
        if (numero==0){
            break;
        }
    }

    int indice=0;
    if( neg ){
        indice++;
        input[0]='-';
    }
    for (int i=size-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        input[indice]=parteEntera[i]+'0'; 
        indice++;
    }

    input[indice]='.';
    indice++;

    numeroFloat=(numeroFloat-(int)numeroFloat);
    for (int i=1; i<=6 ; i++)
    {
        numeroFloat=numeroFloat*10;
        cifra= (long)numeroFloat;          
        numeroFloat=numeroFloat-cifra;
        input[indice]=char(cifra)+48;
        indice++;
    }
        input[indice]='\0';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. 
you can use my function, it converts the gps coordinate from DMS format to Decimal Degree.

```
void convert2Degrees(char* input){
 char res[40];
 float deg;
 float minutes;
 float seconds;
 char aux[10] ="";
 //latitude format: DDmm.mmmm'
 // get 'degrees' from input parameter
 aux[0] = input[0];
 aux[1] = input[1];
 aux[2] = '\0';

 // convert string to integer and add it to final float variable
 deg = atoi(aux);
 // get 'minutes' from input parameter
 for ( int i=0; i<7; i++ ){
   aux[i] = input[i+2];
 }
 aux[7] = '\0';
 // convert string to integer and add it to final float variable
 minutes = atoi(aux);
 // get 'seconds' from input parameter
 for ( int i=0; i<2; i++ ){
   aux[i] = aux[i+3];
 }
 aux[3] = '\0';
 seconds = atoi(aux);
 // add minutes to degrees
 deg = deg + minutes/60 + seconds/3600;
 dtostrf(deg, 2, 10, res);
 strncpy(input, res,9);
}
```